# Are we already at infinite time?

Tags: vedanta, time

It is a common point across all vedantic darshanas that the universe undergoes cyclic creation and destruction. There are infinite such cycles going back in time and infinite such cycles are yet to come. That means, infinite years/months/units of time have already passed by. We are already at infinite time? But how can we ever reach infinite time? **How can infinite number of years ever pass by?** Infinity can never be physically realized. But vedanta says that we are already at infinite time! How is this possible? Have any vedantic philosophers tried to address this issue?

Comment: Why can't infinite number of years pass by? If years were finite, everyone would have got Moksha by now.

Comment: You are reifying time, and this will cause much confusion. You might like to google the phrases 'Holy Instant', Divine Moment' and 'Perennial Now'. For a mathematical explanation of time in accord with the Vedas (or so it seems to me) you could read the mathematician Hermann Weyl on the continuum, or a text called 'Open World'. He points out that we do not experience the passing of time and explains the continuum of mathematics and physics as a mental construction.

Comment: i do not think this question has any answer from scriotures except mentioning that the creation is Anaadi or endless.

Comment: not all darshanas/schools of thaught believe in moksha for everyone all are equal all are brahman himself.. @chinmaysarupria some will get moksha some will get andhamas some will always be in the cycle.. then only this infinite theory holds good.. otherwise as you said you have nullify the Vedic statement that creation annadhi or have infinite cycle, there is one way to escape say that this is mere illusion.. then no need to explain infinite because infinite is also illusion

Comment: @PrasannaR "some will always be in the cycle" There is none who will forever remain in the cycle.

Comment: this creation is sriman Narayana only a handful of jeevas is considered for current creation there are crores of jeevas yet to come in these brahmas cycle.. those Jeeva will not reduce because some wont go to moksha and andamas will be in cycle.. @chinmaysarupria

Comment: @PrasannaR Jivas are infinite but there is no one who has no chance for Moksha.

Comment: See its like this if you move towards God, God will come near, if you move away from God God will be away from you not other way round.. its not circle you just turn away from god keep on moving suddenly you bump on God. is it ever possible.. If there is infinite time for jiva to be in moksha, than the converse must be true there is infinite time jiva can be in andhamas ( without attaining moksha) if you say only one way than it violates basic principle of mathematics @chinmaysarupria  Im not conversant in mathematics. if A is there A' complement should be there according to set theory

Answer (score 1):

Its all in the mind. The universe is a dream. If I dream of playing a badminton match, subconsciously I would assume that I was born from my mothers womb and so many things that  in reality never happened. Science says universe took billions of years for life to come on earth. But Christianity says that it took seven days. In a dream, you can choose to see as behind in time as possible, but that doesn't mean that really happened. In a dream, we can never talk about the start or end of time. That is why time is infinite both in past and future till you wake up. We are already at infinite time would be true in this sense. It may have intended to tell us that its time to wake up.

Comment: Wake up from what?

Comment: Wake up from this dream of life filled with duality and realize the Real- Adwaitha

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Enlightened state is the wake state and what we call the normal day to day state is actually abnormal dream state. How can there be perception if all are me? Life has to be a dream of which realization is the wake state. All this is as per Ashtavakra geetha and Mudakopanishad and Ramanas talks and Nisargadatta Maharaj books.

Comment: What is the difference between the enlightened state and the abnormal dream state?

Comment: There are no others(no duality of seer and seen). No good no bad no joy no grief no pain no pleasure no desire no fear no one else other than Self or God. All changes are unreal. Awareness of this leads to experience of absence of

Comment: You are God dreaming the dream of this universe attached to a role in the Divine drama(dream) thereby thinking that you are vikas and..... All that are the characteristics of a role played in your dream. You have nothing to do with Wikash. Realising that you are That DREAMER and not just a temporary limited existence, (THATH TWAM ASI) is what is being awake. Rama was awake. Krishna was awake. Hence they could do anything because it was their dream! You too are the same Krishna but are still in swapnavastha